# Unable to Record Macros using Excel 2010 Solver

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, solver

I have been unable to record a macro which should have recorded the Solver in action in Excel 2010. Am I able to do this or am I missing something?

I am able to use Solver manually, if this helps.

Comment: I recall having the same problem a while ago, and remember there is a way to use solver in VBA. Hopefully this helps: http://peltiertech.com/Excel/SolverVBA.html

Comment: I have added the add-in into my Excel,. not sure how to reference it though and the article you linked is an older version of excel

Comment: I struggle to understand why this has been downvoted considering it is a nontrivial problem to solve.

Comment: Clearly 265 other people were also interested in this nontrivial problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel 2010:

Open up the Visual Basic window and then click Tools --> References --> then make sure that the SOLVER one is ticked.

Essentially you need to make sure that the Solver library of functions is referenced.